# CUDA cudaDeviceProp has no member error building deviceQuery sample

Tags: cuda

I tried to compile the CUDA device query package on my cluster but when doing a make at location /NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK/C/src/deviceQuery, I get the following error

```
deviceQuery.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
deviceQuery.cpp:119: error: 'struct cudaDeviceProp' has no member named 'maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor'
make: *** [obj/x86_64/release/deviceQuery.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Can somebody help me with this error.

Thank You.

Comment: Make sure you have the same cuda SDK release installed on the cluster as you have installed on your local machine.

Comment: And make sure you have the SDK release that matches the CUDA release you are using to compile.

Comment: Try running deviceQueryDrv. If that works, there is something wrong with your CUDA runtime (CUDART) installation.  If deviceQueryDrv does not work, there is a problem with your driver installation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor` has been added to `struct cudaDeviceProp` in CUDA 4.0. One of your machines has to have an older CUDA tookit.